# loading Json file in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have tried to load a `JSON` file in pandas with this code 
and I have this error in the fist line. I think that same thing is wrong in json structure because I tried also with `pd.read_json` and it didn't work. What is wrong here?

```
Name_file='data582750.txt'
l=[]
with open(Name_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        l.append(line)
data = json.loads(l)
json_normalize(data)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-c050037c7cb9> in <module>()
----> 1 data = json.loads(l)
C:\Users\demighaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)

    337             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    338             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 339         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    340     if cls is None:
    341         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Users\demighaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    362 
    363         """
--> 364         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    365         end = _w(s, end).end()
    366         if end != len(s): 

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

The first line in the file is :

```
'{"Operator":0,"Device":"F0FCC","Time":1494854190,"FormattedTime":"2017-05-15 15:16:30 +0200 CEST","Data":"042911e3c78f2193262c58b2","JSONDecodedData":"{"Service":{"S":{"Typ":0,"Version":2,"Vdd":0},"Cpt":2,"Start":0},"ExtTemperature":[22.25,21.5,21.5,21.5,21.5,22],"Moisture":[50,50,49,49,49,50],"IntTemperature":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}","Snr":"48.21","ComputedLocation":{"Lat":0,"Lng":0},"LinkQuality":"EXCELLENT"}\n'
```

Comment: Don't post code as an image - put a [MCVE] in your post that people can copy out (as text) to check and edit.

Comment: Props for removing the image and adding text, but you should try to format the code correctly to get help - it's difficult to see what's going on here.

Comment: your issue is unreadable... you should take the time edit you post to improve indentation!! just a simple button `{}` to auto indent....

Answer (score 2):

Please post code, not images...

Anyway: ***from what I can see*** you have a [jsonlines file](http://jsonlines.org/) - each line is a the representation of a distinct json object by itself. `json.loads()` expects a single string (representing a single json object), not a `list`. So the obvious solution is decode the json lines on the fly instead of passing the whole list, ie:

```
data = []
with open("you/file.ext") as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
json_normalize(data)
```

Edit: given your comment you *may* not have a jsonlines file. If it's a real json file then just pass the whole file content to `json.loads()` or, even simpler, pass the file itself to `json.load()`. And do the world a favour: read that freaking manual before posting, it will save everyone's time :-/

Comment: I have this error with your code ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 154 (char 153)

Comment: If you want good answers, post good questions : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Should be `json.loads(l[0])` judging by your picture... The `json.loads` function only takes `string` or `buffer` but you're providing a `list`

Comment: ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 154 (char 153)

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some problem with JSON data! Validate the data using a JSON validator. You can just copy-paste date on [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and check if JSON is properly formatted or not.